# Trying to find and get rid of this \u0000 from my json

Tags: php, json, string

This is my `$var` from `json_encode`:

```
{
"key1":"\u0000data1",
"key2":"\u0000data2",
"key3":"\u0000data3",
"key4":"\u0000data4
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
echo json_encode(str_replace ("\\u0000", "",  $var));
```

in order to get rid of the preceding `\u0000` that's showing up, the line above doesn't work to strip it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to apply the function the other way round:

```
echo str_replace('\\u0000', '', json_encode($var));
```

This is because $var is an array. You'd have to iterate over all its entries and look for the `\0` byte otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar.

[This question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325447/array-to-object-and-object-to-array-in-php-interesting-behaviour/6325631#6325631) helped me understand the root cause of the problem.

I overcame this by realising that my class properties (equivalent to each `keyn` in your question) didn't really need to be `protected`.  By making them `public` I side-stepped the issue altogether.

I suppose it's up to you to decide if this is best practice or suited to your project however.