# Array to Object and Object to Array in PHP - interesting behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

Can you explain the next interesting behaviour?

```
class test {
  //Class *test* has two properties, public and private.
  public $xpublic = 'x1';
  private $xprivate = 'x2';
}
$testObj = new test();
```

Let's convert `$testObj` to array.

```
settype($testObj, 'array');
var_dump($testObj);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["xpublic"]=> string(3) "x1"
  ["testxprivate"]=> string(4) "x2"
}
```

OK, `xprivate` property becomes `testxprivate`

Let's convert this array to object.

```
$newObj = (object)$testObj;
var_dump($newObj);
```

Result:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["xpublic"]=> string(3) "xxx"
  ["xprivate":"test":private]=> string(4) "xxx3"
}
```

`$newObj` is a `stdClass` object.

And the question is:

Why does `testxprivate` become a private property `xprivate` (not `testxprivate`) of the new object?  How does PHP know that `$testObj` array was an object?

If I define the equal array:

```
$testArray = array('xpublic'=>'x1', 'testxprivate'=>'x2');
```

and then convert it to object:

```
var_dump((object)$testArray);
```

I'll get the object with two **public** properties `xpublic` and `testxprivate` as expected:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["xpublic"]=> string(2) "x1"
  ["testxprivate"]=> string(2) "x2"
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The array key contains a marker that this should be a private property of the class test.

Compare your scripts output with the following:

```
$array = array(
    "xpublic" => "x1", 
    # this will become a private member:
    "\x00test\x00xprivate" => "x2",
    # this will become a protected member:
    "\x00*\x00xprotected" => "x3"
);

var_dump($array);

$obj = (object) $array;

var_dump($obj);
```

When serialized, the same string is used to describe the private members.

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["xpublic"]=>
  string(2) "x1"
  ["testxprivate"]=>
  string(2) "x2"
  ["*xprotected"]=>
  string(2) "x3"
}

object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["xpublic"]=>
  string(2) "x1"
  ["xprivate":"test":private]=>
  string(2) "x2"
  ["xprotected":protected]=>
  string(2) "x3"
}
```

In the output of `var_dump()`, the null bytes are not visible.

(Update: Added protected class member)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the PHP engine conserves the class structure internaly and simply gives some kind of an array wrapper, and thus when you cast it again it remains private, though I can't assure this at 100%.