# Associative array with 2 names that are the same?

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP script that updates some tracking numbers based on an uploaded CSV file. The import worked fine for some time, then the exports started having quotation marks around the values. I thought this would be fine, but it started rejecting the files. Doing some debugging and var_dumps, I discovered a very strange situation I have never seen before - An associative array with two indices *with the same name*. I ran the code setting the fields (shown below) and added a line:

```
$v['order_id'] = '119205';
```

After running that line, the var_dump was as follows:

```
array(15) {
  ["order_id"]=>
  string(6) "119205"
  ["Tracking Number"]=>
  string(22) "6735675476254654756"
  ["Postage"]=>
  string(4) "1.64"
  ["order_id"]=>
  string(6) "119205"
}
```

Some fields removed for brevity. As you can see, there are two `["order_id"]` indices. How is this even possible?

Here is the code that sets the values of the array dumped above:

```
$v = array();
    foreach ($map as $k => $n) {
    $v[$n] = @$data[$k];
}
```

with `$map` being the CSV header row. Trying to reference `$v['order_id']` without running the `$v['order_id'] = '119205';` line resulted in this error:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: order_id in /dir/to/php/file/php_file.php</b> on line 29
```

Manually setting the index worked as expected, pulling the rest of the data from `$v` without issue.

**EDIT:**

Dumping the array_keys resulted in:

```
[0]=>
string(11) "order_id"
```

and:

```
[14]=>
string(8) "order_id"
```

making the first one *three characters* longer.

var_export still resulted in identical indices.

How can I get rid of these invisible characters? I've already tried `$v[trim($n)] = @$data[$k];` in the `foreach()`.

Comment: There *are* corner cases in which an associative array with duplicate keys can be created, due to how they work in PHP.

Comment: your indices may have invisible characters. Try by replacing `var_dump()` with `var_export()`.

Comment: try `strip_tags()` instead of `trim()` - that should handle cases where NULs are in the string, not just the beginning and the end

Comment: sadly, `strip_tags()` didn't change anything.

Comment: maybe they're not NULs . . . if that's the case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string) should do the trick.  It might be interesting to loop through the odd keys and determine what characters are causing you issues - [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) would help with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `var_dump(array_keys($v))`. Find the key that looks like `order_id` and make sure the string's length is exactly 8. I suspect there may be a NUL character in there, which would give it a length of 9 and cause it to not respond to `order_id`.

Comment: I've updated my original question based on your helpful response.

Comment: To further examine what characters are there, try looping through all characters in the string and outputting their [`ord`](http://php.net/ord) values. This will tell you exactly what extra characters you have and where they are.

Comment: Success! Changing the assignment line to `$v[trim($n, chr(239).chr(187).chr(191))] = @$data[$k];` fixed it. However, it's not very pretty... If anyone knows a better way to do this, please let me know. Accepting your answer - Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see now. The sequence `239-187-191` is a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is there because your file is in UTF-8. You should be able to save the file as UTF-8 without BOM, and that'll solve your problem.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have any say in how the file is saved. Is there a way to remove these after the fact?

Comment: If you're using anything like `file_get_contents` before processing the file contents, you could use `str_replace` (or `preg_replace` with a start-of-string anchor) to remove it.

Comment: I'm using `fgetcsv()` so that's not an option. However, I moved the `trim()` to just run it once on the first map index, which works the same way as before but without running the `trim()` every loop. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> In the output of `var_dump()`, the null bytes are not visible.

Technically you can not have two times the same key in PHP in an array. It might be that `var_dump` is not giving the right keys here (e.g. probably some null-chars or other non-displayable chars are dropped).

Instead you might want to check, what's going on:

```
var_dump(array_keys($data));
```

Maybe it helps, the following is a related question which demonstrates when `var_dump` hides some information:

- [Array to Object and Object to Array in PHP - interesting behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325447/array-to-object-and-object-to-array-in-php-interesting-behaviour/6325631#6325631)