# Understanding what \u0000 is in PHP / JSON and getting rid of it

Tags: php, json

I haven't a clue what is going on but I have a string inside an array. It must be a string as I have ran this on it first:

```
$array[0] = (string)$array[0];
```

If I output $array[0] to the browser in plain text it shows this:

```
hellothere
```

But if I JSON encode $array I get this:

```
hello\u0000there
```

Also, I need to separate the 'there' part (the bit after the \u0000), but this doesn't work:

```
explode('\u0000', $array[0]);
```

I don't even know what \u0000 is or how to control it in PHP.

I did see this link: [Trying to find and get rid of this \u0000 from my json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892967/trying-to-find-and-get-rid-of-this-u0000-from-my-json)
...which suggests str_replacing the JSON that is generated. I can't do that (and need to separate it as mentioned above first) so I then checked Google for 'php check for backslash \0 byte' but I still can't work out what to do.

Comment: `\u` is used to escape unicode symbols, basically the unicode equivalent to `\x00`.

Comment: \u0000 is unicode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string

Comment: Did you try googling "\u0000" at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\uXXXX` is the JSON Unicode escape notation (`X` is hexadecimal).

In this case, it means the `0` ASCII char, aka the NUL byte, to split it you can either do:

```
explode('\u0000', json_encode($array[0]));
```

Or better yet:

```
explode("\0", $array[0]); // PHP doesn't use the same notation as JSON
```

Comment: explode("\0", $array[0]) - that's the one. None of the others worked. I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me. Thanks

Comment: PHP does not understand \uHHHH notation within strings.

Comment: @Nicholas: Right. It does understand `\HH` however.

Comment: ...or better yet `str_replace('\0', '', $json_data)`

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Yes, but that won't separate like the OP wanted.

Comment: Using `trim` is simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 12):

The string you have is `"hello\0world"`, or `"hello\x00world"` whatever you prefer. If you `echo` it, the null symbol `\0` won't be displayed, thats why you see `helloworld` instead, but `json_encode` will detect it and escape it as it does to any other special character, thats why its replaced by a visible `\u0000` string.

In my way of seeing it, json is encoding the string perfectly, the `\u0000` is there to do its job of reproducing the inputted string in a json encoded way. You don't have to touch its output. If you don't want that `\u0000` there you should fix its **input** instead.

Comment: How to fix the input, I have a UTF-8 encoded file - but no way I can find any null characters in there - please help

Comment: @almaruf By removing the characters from the string before encoding it, of course. And yeah, null characters won't be displayed and give you the impression that they are simply not there, but at binary level they are and a `str_replace()` will be able to find and replace them.

Answer (score 11):

you can simply do `trim($str)` without giving it a charlist

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone need it to apply to the whole array

```
$data = (array)json_decode(str_replace('\u0000*\u0000', '', json_encode($data)));
```

Answer (score 2):

`\uXXXX` is the unicode symbol with code `XXXX` (hexadecimal).
For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx

If you really get `0000` - then it's just the char with code `0`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today and I sorted it out by replacing \u0000 in my array with "" before sending it back to the client.

```
echo str_replace('\\u0000', "", json_encode($send));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've found the symbol inside serialized Laravel job's payload json, something like `s:8:"\0*\0order";` (or `s:8:"\u0000*\u0000order";`) which meant that serialized object's property `order` has visibility `protected` on a moment of serialization

Answer (score 0):

Try `explode("\u0000", $array[0]);`, making sure you use double quotes. With single quotes it's going to parse the literal 6 character value.

As others have mentioned, `\u0000` is the Unicode NUL character.

Comment: Except that it's `\u0000` and not `\0000`.