# How to json_encode PHP object returned by Google Calendar API

Tags: php, json, google-calendar-api

First and foremost - I am not a PHP developer. I concentrate on front-end but am wanting to expand my knowledge/play around with some personal projects to further my understanding. Therefore some of my terminology and fundamental understand of what I'm trying to achieve may be a little ... 'off'.

I have followed all the steps provided by Google and have managed to get to a point with the Google Calendar API where I can list calendar events using a simple `var_dump()`

My problem lies in trying to make this data useful. I want to do this with JSON. I am aware of the `json_encode()` function but am not sure how I should be using it within the context of what I am trying to achieve (that is to have a JSON file which can hook into the data I need to ultimately display a calendar on the front-end). I am aware that `json_encode()` respects property visibility/scope but this is my problem - I cannot figure out how to ensure `json_encode()` will also encode the protected properties/methods in the object I am returned.

Here is my code:

```
$eventsArgs = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'singleEvents' => true,
);

$events = $calendarService->events->listEvents('***@gmail.com', $eventsArgs);

$listEvents = fopen('list_events.json', 'w');

    foreach($events->getItems() as $event) {
        fwrite($listEvents, json_encode($event, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }

fclose($listEvents);
```

I am wanting to pull in protected properties/methods such as `start` and `end` as displayed here with a simple `var_dump()`...

```
["modelData":protected]=> array(5) {
["creator"]=>
array(3) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(23) "***@gmail.com"
  ["displayName"]=>
  string(14) "***"
  ["self"]=>
  bool(true)
}
["organizer"]=>
array(3) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(23) "***@gmail.com"
  ["displayName"]=>
  string(14) "***"
  ["self"]=>
  bool(true)
}
["start"]=>
array(1) {
  ["dateTime"]=>
  string(25) "2014-04-27T05:00:00+01:00"
}
["end"]=>
array(1) {
  ["dateTime"]=>
  string(25) "2014-04-27T06:00:00+01:00"
}
```

I am really trying to educate myself here and unfortunately have hit a wall and the answers I find, if I'm honest, are a little too technical for my understanding. Technical as well as non-technical explanations welcome!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem, as you pointed out, is that properties you want to access are protected and `json_encode` respects that and will not access them. [Read up on public, private, and protected. Good stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Because the values are protected, you'll have to pull the data you want out of `$event` and into an unprotected array and then `json_encode` that. Untested code follows:

```
$eventsArgs = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'singleEvents' => true,
);

$events = $calendarService->events->listEvents('***@gmail.com', $eventsArgs);

$listEvents = fopen('list_events.json', 'w');

foreach($events->getItems() as $event) {
    $jsonArr = array(
        "start"=>$event->start->dateTime
        ,"end"=>$event->end->dateTime
    );

    fwrite($listEvents, json_encode($jsonArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

fclose($listEvents);
```

Now even that code might not work. You may have to find the appropriate method (that's 'method' as in: function belonging to a class) to get the properties you want out of a Google Calendar Event, and then put them in an array and than json_encode it.

So the 'getter' method might be: `$event->get('start')->dateTime` or something. I have no experience with the Google Calendar API, so can't really help you in that regard

Lastly, know that you can have the PHP script `echo` the `json_encode`d results so you won't need the file. (of course, I have no idea what all of your code looks like, so that could be a bad idea)

```
foreach(...) {
    echo json_encode($yourArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to give that a go ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, Terminus - worked perfectly! I'm now able to construct the exact type of object I need.

Comment: Nice. Good luck with your programming

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you! I finally found:

```
$json = json_encode( (array)$events);
```

Answer is from another post:[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836592/serializing-php-object-to-json)

Please Note:

---

It produces Unicode NUL characters: \u0000*\u0000 on the outer array keys. But the full structure with the start and end values remains. If you are interested in removing the Nul chars you can use str_replace() or explode. [Understanding what \u0000 is in PHP / JSON and getting rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499955/understanding-what-u0000-is-in-php-json-and-getting-rid-of-it)

Terminus's answer above is great but using this was preferable for my situation because I needed to match a different json file from google node.js api .

Comment: this is super elegant!