# PHP str_replace for back slash

Tags: php

I need to replace \ with '' in following string.

```
$x = "FBU4061\0258";
```

When I do `$x = str_replace('\\', '', $x);`

It returns FBU40618,

Is there any workaround to get FBU40610258.

**Note: I need to do this inside double quotes. Within single quotes it returns the desired value without problem.**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @RensTillmann, It does not work with double quotes, please see my note

Comment: Then create a variable and then do whatever you want? I don't understand why that would make a difference.

Comment: I think that the point where it's in double quotes is where it becomes too late. As soon as you use the variable, `\025` is converted to a character: https://eval.in/465229

Comment: @RensTillmann, When you use double quoted strings, PHP does an escape sequence replacement, and \0 is the NUL byte.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, Yes. is there any workaround ?

Comment: <?php $str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";  // Outputs: Is your name O'reilly? echo stripslashes($str); ?>

Comment: Can you change the definition of `$x`?

Comment: @RensTillmann, It would work with regular strings, but my scenario is a different case. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499955/understanding-what-u0000-is-in-php-json-and-getting-rid-of-it

Comment: Note that stripslashes will work with both double and single quotes.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, Actually $x is coming form the database, what we need is json_encode($x, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES). But we get the result of that value is "FBU4061\u00158", So we thought of removing the slash or replacing it before encoding.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the value of `$x` before you do anything to it?

Comment: Why not :) not much we can do to help you if you can't provide an accurate representation of the variable that you retrieve from the database

Comment: @RobbieAverill, sorry I misunderstood you. When I var_dump too "FBU40618" get this value.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, this is a coincidence, when \ and 0 are together, it escapes the character when it is inside double quotes.

Comment: Maybe solution would be to change the value in the query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: @RensTillmann We are evaluating this option too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best chance is to do a mysql replace query:

Change the value in the query:

`SELECT REPLACE('http://yourdomain.com', 'http', 'https');`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

You might also try this instead:

`UPDATE table
 SET field_name = replace(field, 'http, 'https')`

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/how-do-i-remove-backslashes-from-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 5):

What's probably confusing you here is that double quoted strings interpret this string very differently from a single quoted string. Your string `"FBU4061\0258"` in PHP will interpret the `\02` part of your string as an STX (or start of text) character (i.e. ASCII character `02`).

Just try run the code `var_dump("FBU4061\0258");` in PHP and see for yourself how the output is not what you would expect. You can even do `var_dump(bin2hex("FBU4061\0258"));` and see the hexadecimal representation of your string for further clarification...

### Example

```
var_dump(bin2hex('\02'));
// string(6) "5c3032"
var_dump(bin2hex("\02"));
// string(2) "02"
```

See the difference?

[This is all thoroughly documented behavior in the manual](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double).

> `\[0-7]{1,3}`    the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation

So in order to get a string literal of `FBU4061\0258` you must escape the backslash inside of double quoted strings.

```
$x = "FBU4061\\0258";
$x = str_replace('\\', '', $x);
var_dump($x); //string(11) "FBU40610258"
```

Notice this is because you are placing a string literal in your code. If this string were retrieved from your database, however, this interpolation wouldn't take place, because it's already a string literal.

### Again ...

```
var_dump("FBU4061\\0258"); // string(12) "FBU4061\0258"
var_dump("FBU4061\0258");  // string(9) "FBU40618"
```

Look at the obvious difference in the length of the string!

Comment: I understand the problem and we are evaluating possible solutions. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

use php `stripslashes`

```
echo stripslashes('FBU4061\0258');
```

or try this code :-

```
function removeslashes($string)
{
    $string=implode("",explode("\\",$string));
    return stripslashes(trim($string));
}

$text="FBU4061\0258";
echo removeslashes($text);
```

[Stripslashes more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: As I told above it can be done with single quotes, I need to use double quotes. If you use double quotes, you will see it does bot work

Comment: That doesn't have to be a problem?

Comment: @RensTillmann, Please try and see, actually above value comes from the database and so it come with double quotes

Comment: @Rahautos the example in the question uses double quotes so this is not an accurate answer